# Call AWS API from React (Typescript) functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api, react-functional-component

(I'm fairly new to React and especially how to link it to a backend server. Sorry if this is an obvious question)

I have a functional React component `Game` that keeps an evaluation of the current position. I have created an API with AWS to return an evaluation number (random value in (-10, 10) for now). I have this function inside my component:

```
const [evaluation, setEvaluation] = React.useState<number>(0.0);

// ...

const getEvalAfterMove = async (board: string[], nextPlayer: string) => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch('my/api/link');
        const data = await response.json();
        setEvaluation(data);
    }
        
    fetchData();
};
```

Basically, within the `Game` component there is a `GameGrid` component which itself is made of `Square` components. `getEvalAfterMove` gets passed down until each `Square` (which are simple divs) has their `onClick` attribute set to call it. When I open the page on a browser, however, `TypeError: Failed to Fetch` gets logged whenever I click a square (calling `getEvalAfterMove`) and nothing else happens (I'm not able to get a value) - the API works, I can go to the invoke URL and it gives me a JSON with the random value.

Am I right in saying that `getEvalAfterMove` executes separately from the rest of my React app because it is asynchronous? How can I update my `evaluation` useState after every square click using  API calls? Would I need to add a loading screen to display while the app awaits the response?

Comment: If you want to wait till the response is done, there are 2 options. SSR will call the API before the client renders (HTML). Or you can simply placed a loader in you client side until the API response. This is why I consider NEXTjs better than React, you can manage SSR very easy

Comment: And yes, the function is running asynchronous, this is why it returns a promise. When you use async/await you are just waiting for the promise to return some JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the accepted configuration for fetch.

```
const response = await fetch('my/api/link', {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
});
```

Keep in mind that you will need to find what method your API accepts, GET, POST...
Also, the content type may not be application/json, that is just the most common one.